# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to insert a row in a table called Appointments, that looks like this:

[image: table Appointments]

But when i try to add the row, like so:

```
dbAppointments.Appointments.Add(newAppointment);
dbAppointments.SaveChanges();
```

It throws the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException in EntityFramework.dll

and I have no idea why. The parameters of `newAppointment` match with the table columns (because `newAppointment` is an object of the `Appointments` model, that came from the database) and the values are valid so I don't understand.

Can someone please tell me what can be happening ?

Thank you in advance!

**[EDIT]**: this is how `newAppointment` is being created:

```
Appointments newAppointment = new Appointments()
        {
            UserID = 2020,
            ClientID = 3,
            Subject = "nothing",
            Date = "2022-01-23",
            Hour = "10:30",
            Duration = 15,
            Place = "office",
            Occurred = false
        };
```

The output:

[image: output]

**[SOLVED]**

Comment: Is there an error message with the exception?  Can you share the code that constructs a `newAppointment`?

Comment: No, the only thing that comes in the output is "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll".

Comment: Sure, i'll edit the question to add the construction of newAppointment

Comment: Show a screenshot of this output. If it's a logfile, place a breakpoint at the location the log message is formed; the answer to "what's the error message?" is available but either you're not posting it because you're not sure where to look or it's being thrown away before you look at whatever is showing you

Comment: @CaiusJard added the screenshot. I know where the exception is being thrown i just dont understand why is being thrown if all the values are valid

Comment: There may be more details in the exception (see Message property).  From your code, my guess is that UserId=2020 is violating a primary key constraint (try using a unique value), but can't say for sure w/o seeing the exception message.

Comment: @SteveWongthe userID is a foreing key in this table, so 2020 it's a user's id that actually exists in the table users

Comment: Really need you to get a debugger halted at the point this save is being done. Run the code in debug/dev env, connected to the same DB that whatever system is throwing is also connected to, and run it.. As this messge is likley coming from a catch handler, turn on "break when thrown" - Debug menu>>Exceptions Settings>>in the panel put a tick next to "CLR"

Comment: And when you do find that place, and you see the catch is some logging that only logs the type of the thrown execption, upgrade it so it logs the .Message of every exception in the tree (flatten .InnerException, not just report on the outer one)

Comment: Ok... i found the problem. My entity models are in the Data Access Layer, and that's where my connection strings are saved, and i forgot to add those connection strings in the startup project. Added the connection strings to the project that where i need them and now its working. Thank you so much for your help guys !

Comment: No worries, but do change that logging to be more useful.. It'll save you having to hit up SO for some rubber duck next time :D